# Change child image style

Tags: javascript, image-gallery

I am using this script for a simple image gallery. On the last line, I am trying to change the border of the image within 'this' but the style is not changing for some reason. What have I done wrong?

```
$('.gallery-image').on('click',function(){
    var bigCurrent = $('.hero-image').attr('src'); //the current large image src
    var bigThumb = $('.hero-image').attr('data-smSrc'); //the thumb version src of the current large image
    var thumbSm = $(this).attr('src'); //the currently being clicked on thumb's src
    var thumbLgSrc = $(this).attr('data-lgSrc'); //the large version src of the currently being clicked on thumb

    $('.hero-image').attr('src', thumbLgSrc);
    $('img', this).css('border','2px solid #fff');

});
```

UPDATE:
This is working and follows the corrections made in some comments below

```
$('.gallery-image').on('click',function(){
    var bigCurrent = $('.hero-image').attr('src'); //the current large image src
    var bigThumb = $('.hero-image').attr('data-smSrc'); //the thumb version src of the current large image
    var thumbSm = $('img', this).attr('src'); //the currently being clicked on thumb's src
    var thumbLgSrc = $(this).attr('data-lgSrc'); //the large version src of the currently being clicked on thumb

    $('.hero-image').attr('src', thumbLgSrc);

    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');

     $('img', this).addClass('selected'); 
});
```

Comment: can you add a fiddle or a link to the rogue site

Comment: Any errors in the console? Or does it just don't work as intended?

Comment: Sorry, real link: http://penumbralux.com/project/marisol/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing this failing, chances are, you are trying to select the wrong thing.

You have `$(this).attr('src')`, which implies that `this` is the image node itself, because that attribute is specific to `img`.  Yet you try to select an `img` within `this` context, and since `img` can't have children, it's unlikely there are any `img` nodes to find.

Try changing it to just `$(this).css(...)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for responding. '$(this)' is the div that holds the image, so I'm trying to select its child img tag to apply the styles too.

Comment: You were correct, I was not selecting the correct thing. It needed to be $(this, 'img'), just reversed order.

Comment: You should not have an attribute of `src` on a div.  This is not a supported attribute.  HTML5 supports data-* attributes for this reason.   If you want to store the `src` of the image outside the `img` node, you *should* be using a data-* attribute instead.

Comment: In addition, `$(this, 'img')` doesn't mean anything useful.  That means select `this` within the context of `img` tags in the document.  jQuery might short circuit this, but that shouldn't select anything useful, unless `this` truly is a child of an image tag.

Comment: I see what you're saying and have adjusted my question with the code that is working for me now. The strange thing is, the old code worked too, so while I understand your response, I'm confused why it worked just as well the incorrect way...